# How to use angular DatePipe with 0 value?

Tags: angular, angular11, date-pipe

I've been try to use angular DatePipe to convert number to date, but I think there is something wrong. I don't know where ("maybe some bug").

**For an example in my typescript:**

```js
const ONE_SECOND = 1000
setInterval(() => {
  this.dateInTime  += ONE_SECOND
}, ONE_SECOND);
```

**My HTML:**

```html
<h4 class="text-primary">
  Result: {{ dateInTime | date: 'HH : mm : ss' }}
</h4>
```

I really hope the result is: `00:00:00` but it's not like that. I got the result always: `07:00:00`.

I don't know where's the mistake of my code. Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timezone definition. Your timezone is +7

```
Result: {{ dateInTime | date: 'HH : mm : ss':'+0' }}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance. It really helpfull